# Prove that if $n$ divides a repunit, then the length of the repunit is less than $n$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was working on some programming challenges and came across a problem that concerns finding the minimum repunit length $k$ for a given $n$ such that $n$ divides the repunit. There is an imposed condition that $GCD(n, 10) = 1$, of course.

In particular, let $A(n)$ be the length of the shortest repunit $r$ such that $n$ divides $r$.

---

First, I tried the Pigeonhole Principle. Notice that for length $k$, $r$ can be written as

$$r = \frac{10^k - 1}{9}$$

Modulo $n$, there are at most $n$ residues. If $k \ge n + 2$, then there are $n + 1$ possible remainders of $r$ modulo $n$ for length $i < k$. By the Pigeonhole Principle, there exists two repunits $r_a, r_b$ with length $a < b$ less than $k$ that has the same remainder modulo $n$, and therefore has difference $0$ modulo $n$.

However their difference is not a repunit and this doesn't seem to be of any use, because I haven't showed that for $k \ge n + 2$, there exists another repunit with length less than $k$ that is divisible by $n$ in order to set up a contradiction.

---

Secondly, I tried using Euler's Theorem. For $n$, let $k$ be the minimum repunit length such that $n$ divides $r$. Assume that $k \ge n$. Then,

$$\frac{10^{k - \phi(n)}\cdot10^{\phi(n)} - 1}{9}\equiv 0 \pmod n$$

Since by Euler's Theorem $10^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$,

$$\frac{10^{k - \phi(n)} - 1}{9}\equiv 0 \pmod n$$

leading to a contradiction that $k$ is the minimum exponent, as $k - \phi(n) < k$ satisfies the condition as well. Therefore, $k < n$.

However, I am not sure about the validity of assuming $\frac{10^{\phi(n)}}{9} \equiv \frac{1}{9} \pmod n$ which I think is required in order for the second equation to work. I haven't had much experience working with remainder problems where there is a fraction.

I have tried the fundamental definition of $a \equiv b \pmod m \iff m \mid (a - b)$ but have failed.

Comment: The difference of two repunits is a repunit, multiplied with a power of $10$, and you have to use the given $\gcd(n,10)=1$ at *some* point

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ahah! And since $GCD(n, 10) = 1$, $n \not \mid 10^c$. Since $r_b - r_a = 10^c r_d$ and $n$ divides LHS, then it must divide RHS. Since $n \not \mid 10^c$, it must divide $r_d < r$.